# StackOverflow in SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xpath

Hello I have function which creates/updates fields in app.exe.config file

```
        public static void UpdateConfig(string FieldName, string FieldValue, ConfigSelector SectionName = ConfigSelector.AppSettings)
    {
        switch (SectionName)
        {
            case ConfigSelector.Execption:
                {
                   // MessageBox.Show("gg");
                    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
                    if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption") != null)
                    {

                        if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption/List") != null)
                        {
                            // create new node <add key="Region" value="Canterbury" />
                            var nodeRegion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("add");
                            nodeRegion.SetAttribute("key", FieldName);
                            nodeRegion.SetAttribute("value", FieldValue);

                            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption/List").AppendChild(nodeRegion);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var List = xmlDoc.CreateElement("List");
                            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption").AppendChild(List);
                            UpdateConfig(FieldName, FieldValue, SectionName);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var List = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Execption");
                        xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration").AppendChild(List);
                        UpdateConfig(FieldName, FieldValue, SectionName);
                    }

                    xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

                    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("Execption/List");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Function works first Check if xpath configuration/Execption exist, if not exist it creates this path and recalls function again, second time check if configuration/Execption/List path exist if not creates path and recalls function again, and third time adds required fields which is fieldname and fieldvalue,

but I getting System.StackOverflowException in line:

```
if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption") != null)
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save the document after adding the new element, so when you are loading the file in the next iteration the new element isn't there, and `xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/Execption") != null` is still false, so the code creates the element again in infinite recursion and you get `StackOverflowException`.

Just save the document after you change it

```
else
{
    var List = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Execption");
    xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration").AppendChild(List);
    xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    UpdateConfig(FieldName, FieldValue, SectionName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling UpdateConfig recursively, with the exact same arguments already passed to it

```
UpdateConfig(FieldName, FieldValue, SectionName);
```

Since the recursive call happens before the xmlDoc.Save(), it always works on the same content.

Saving before doing the recursive call should fix the issue.